# Long URLs are not wrapped in a two-column layout of Reveal.js rendered from R Markdown

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, multiple-columns, reveal.js

I am trying to produce reveal.js slides from an R Markdown file, where I want to get a two-column layout by applying [Pandoc's fenced divs](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fenced_divs). However, as shown in a picture below, a column that contains a long URL spills over into the other column. What should I do to prevent this undesirable layout?

[image]

## MWE

````
---
author: CLRR
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    self_contained: false
    reveal_plugins: ["notes", "search"]
    transition: slide
    pandoc_args:
      - --wrap=preserve
---

## Without long URL

::: {.columns}

:::: {.column width="49%"}

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
- Fusce molestie lorem lorem, sit amet accumsan ante fermentum a.

::::

:::: {.column width="49%"}

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
- Fusce molestie lorem lorem, sit amet accumsan ante fermentum a.

::::

:::

## With long URL

::: {.columns}

:::: {.column width="49%"}

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
- Fusce molestie lorem lorem, sit amet accumsan ante fermentum a.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304484/two-column-layout-wrapping-around-floated-div

::::

:::: {.column width="49%"}

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
- Fusce molestie lorem lorem, sit amet accumsan ante fermentum a.

::::

:::

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.reveal h1,
.reveal h2,
.reveal h3,
.reveal h4,
.reveal h5,
.reveal h6 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

.reveal h1,
.reveal h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.reveal code{
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  margin: 2px 2px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 24pt;
  */
}

.reveal pre {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 24pt;
  line-height: ;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  */
}

.reveal  pre code {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  */
}

.reveal .slide {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

/*
12pt

|name          |    pt| relative_size|
|:-------------|-----:|-------------:|
|\tiny         |  6.00|      50.00000|
|\scriptsize   |  8.00|      66.66667|
|\footnotesize | 10.00|      83.33333|
|\small        | 10.95|      91.25000|
|\normalsize   | 12.00|     100.00000|
|\large        | 14.40|     120.00000|
|\Large        | 17.28|     144.00000|
|\LARGE        | 20.74|     172.83333|
|\huge         | 24.88|     207.33333|
|\Huge         | 24.88|     207.33333|

*/

.reveal .footer {
  font-size: 83%;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  /* display: inline-flex; */
  /* flex: auto; */
}

.reveal .speaker-controls {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}
```

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
</style>
````

Answer (score 0):

The following css code does the trick:

```css
.uri {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

[image]

## MWE

````
---
author: CLRR
date: | 
  | Last Update: `r format(Sys.time(), '%Y/%m/%d')`）
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    self_contained: false
    reveal_plugins: ["notes", "search"]
    transition: slide
    pandoc_args:
      - --wrap=preserve
---

## Without long URL

::: {.columns}

:::: {.column width="49%"}

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
- Fusce molestie lorem lorem, sit amet accumsan ante fermentum a.

::::

:::: {.column width="49%"}

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
- Fusce molestie lorem lorem, sit amet accumsan ante fermentum a.

::::

:::

## With long URL

::: {.columns}

:::: {.column width="49%"}

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
- Fusce molestie lorem lorem, sit amet accumsan ante fermentum a.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304484/two-column-layout-wrapping-around-floated-div

::::

:::: {.column width="49%"}

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
- Fusce molestie lorem lorem, sit amet accumsan ante fermentum a.

::::

:::

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.reveal h1,
.reveal h2,
.reveal h3,
.reveal h4,
.reveal h5,
.reveal h6 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

.reveal h1,
.reveal h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.reveal code{
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  margin: 2px 2px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 24pt;
  */
}

.reveal pre {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 24pt;
  line-height: ;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  */
}

.reveal  pre code {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  */
}

.reveal .slide {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

/*
12pt

|name          |    pt| relative_size|
|:-------------|-----:|-------------:|
|\tiny         |  6.00|      50.00000|
|\scriptsize   |  8.00|      66.66667|
|\footnotesize | 10.00|      83.33333|
|\small        | 10.95|      91.25000|
|\normalsize   | 12.00|     100.00000|
|\large        | 14.40|     120.00000|
|\Large        | 17.28|     144.00000|
|\LARGE        | 20.74|     172.83333|
|\huge         | 24.88|     207.33333|
|\Huge         | 24.88|     207.33333|

*/

.reveal .footer {
  font-size: 83%;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  /* word-break: break-all; */
  /* display: inline-flex; */
  /* flex: auto; */
}

.uri {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.reveal .speaker-controls {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}
```

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
</style>
````